# Why cumulative sum has a drop

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, cumulative-sum

I have a certain feature in my data which looks like this:

[image: Original column values vs timestamp]

I'm trying to introduce cumulative sum this column in the `DataFrame` as following (the feature is int64 type):

`df['Cumulative'] = df['feature'].cumsum()`

But for unknown reason I have a drop in this function which is weird since the min number in the original column is 0:

[image: Cumulative feature vs timestamp]

Can someone explain why this happens and how can I fix that.Because I just want to sum the feature as it appears.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: It looks like you need to sort the values by date before building the cumulative sum on `feature`, since the last value on the right in your plot is close to the starting value on the left.

Comment: The scale of your plots is not clear, is it possible that your feature is defined as int16 and it wrapped after 32768 value? what is the dtype for the feature?

Comment: @amirhm dtype is int64. The scale of both plots are the same. I just want to have cumulative sum. Which means an increase of the value over the timestamp.

Comment: @Rabinzel but if I 'sort_values()' before 'cumsum()' then I still don't have continuously increasing value

Comment: @Egorsky I wrote a short answer. Did you try it like this? Maybe you didn't reassign the sorted values to the df. My point is, cumsum just sums up the values top to bottom, regardless in which order they appear. If you plot your data chronological after that, your data won't necessarily be increasing at all points.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like in the comments suggested, sorting first and after that build the cumulative sum.
Did you try it like this:

```
df = df.sort_values(by='Date') #where "Date" is the column name of the values on the x-axis
df['cumulative'] = df['feature'].cumsum()
```

Comment: For some reason I didn't figured out that I need to set by which column I sort all of that. Thank you, looks good!